Kids show about kids defending towers with monsters they summoned from their bracelet
When I was a kid there was a show that I loved a lot but it’s lost in my memories now.
My memories of it aren’t too fond because it was a short series but I remember there were four kids (all boys) each from a different elemental tribe (rock, ice, fire and wind) and they grouped together to protect this tower thing, and rebuild it. They would use bracelets to summon monsters to protect them and when they needed to they would combine all the monsters to make a big monster.

The question is a bit scant in detail. When where you a kid? (10 / 20 / 50 years ago?) Were the kids boys or girls? How did the 4 tribes differ? (hair color / skin tone / technology / ...) Consider having a look at Tips for asking Story Identification questions and adding other details to improve the chance someone is able to answer.

It was an animated series and the tribes differed by elements being rock ice fire and wind. They were boys.

Is this Gormiti: Nature Unleashed (2012-2014)...?

Starting in 2012, the Gormiti franchise had a reimagining under the title of Gormiti: Nature Unleashed, animated in CGI and written by Man of Action Studios, who worked on shows such as Ben 10 and Generator Rex. Taking place in an Alternate Continuity, the story follows the adventures of four Gormiti Princes from the tribes of Earth, Sea, Forest and Air, as they try to save the island from the devious Magor, with the help of their guide and mentor, the Old Sage.




